# How to pipe with VBScript objShell.Run?

Tags: vbscript, pipe

this is the command I want to execute:

```
youtube-dl [youtubeurl] -f best -o - | vlc - --file-caching=3000 --fullscreen --play-and-exit
```

This works fine if I just run the command from CMD.

Now I want to call this via speech recognition in wsrmacros with VBScript.

My code:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "cmd /k youtube-dl " & ytlink1 & _
  " -f best -o - | vlc - --file-caching=3000 --fullscreen --play-and-exit", _
  1, True
```

`youtube-dl` properly opens and downloads the desired video, but vlc never launches. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, this works just fine. The problem was in my ytlink1 variable, it had quotes (as part of the variable, like the actual content was like "https://www.youtube.com"). I modified the variable to no longer have quotes and now it works.